# Connect strapi with mongoose to a MongoDb (mLab)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, strapi

I tried to connect Strapi to mLab with this `database.js` config but it doesn't work. I get the error :

```
ConnectorError: connector "strapi-hook-mongoose" not found: Cannot find module 'strapi-connector-strapi-hook-mongoose'
```

Here is my `database.js` config file :

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-hook-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "database": "strapi-test",
        "host": "ds131914.mlab.com",
        "srv": false,
        "port": "31914",
        "username": "root",
        "password": "root010101"
      },
      "options": {
        "authenticationDatabase": "strapi-test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, it appers to me that this `database.js` config was from an old tutorial ([this one](https://medium.com/@tamirp/strapi-%EF%B8%8Fmlab-%EF%B8%8Fheroku-%EF%B8%8F-s3-step-by-step-deployment-for-a-non-developer-1cae3ec3dfe0)). So to solve this probleme, you first need to install `npm i -S strapi-connector-mongoose` in order to install the right connecter.

Now, you need to change you database.js config for the desire environement. In my case, it was production. So edit `config/environement/production/database.js` like this :

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "ds131914.mlab.com",
        "port": "31914",
        "srv": false,
        "database": "strapi-test",
        "username": "root",
        "password": "root010101"
      },
      "options": {
        "authenticationDatabase": "strapi-test",
        "ssl": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like this, it should work !